# Add a vertice to each face

Tags: modeling, loop

I want to fill all of these faces with a vertex

[image].

I suppose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> will work, but is there any alternative faster way to fill it instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> each face?

Answer (score 3):

In <kbd>Face</kbd> mode, use the <kbd>Face</kbd> > <kbd>Poke Faces</kbd> menu. If you then switch back to <kbd>Vertex</kbd> mode you'll see the result.

[image]

Comment: For your other (now deleted) question, you could have just right-clicked and selected Subdivide which would have added the vertices **and** vertical edges as you wanted!